# Creating a new list made up by just a particular coordinate of each point in a given set

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

what I'm trying to do is a weighted fit from points on a list that is formatted like:

```
data={{x_1,y_1,error_1},{x_2,y_2,error_2},{x_3,y_3,error_3},{x_4,y_4,error_4},...}
```

I've read that I need to create a new list, say:

```
    errors={{error_1},{error_2},{error_3},...}
```

to be used in, for example LinearModelFit as a parameter $Weights->1/errors^2$

I'm still absolutely new to mathematica and I'm having issues finding out how to manipulate a list (like data), to create another list (like errors).

*(Also references to specific help pages that teach me how to do this are appreciated)*

Comment: use  `errors = data[[All,3]]`. (see [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html))

Comment: that definitely worked, I'll need to find out a good manual

Comment: Mathematica comes with an extremely large documentation. You find tutorials, reference pages, guide pages, etc.. Look for instance at [this guide page for list manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html). In addition, there are tutorials for beginners you can find [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/resources/).